how to implement android reverb and audio enhancer audio effect
Hi i am trying to implement reverb and audio enhancer but can find little to no documentation on it the code below for both does nothing but i am unsure what i am doing wrong the on touch listeners work as the print out the integers but no reverb effect is applied and the audio does not increase if anyone could point me in the right direction would appreciate as i get no errors in logcat
ReverbController.setOnProgressChangedListener(new DrawspinControllers.onProgressChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int progress) {
                System.out.println("------REVERB--------------------" + progress);//prints 1to15
                PresetReverb reverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
 
                if(progress>2&progress<4){
                    reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
                }else if(progress>=4&progress<6){
                    reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
                } else if(progress>=6&progress<8){
                    reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMHALL);
                }else if(progress>=8&progress<10){
                    reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
                }else if(progress>=10&progress<12){
                    reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE);
                }else if(progress>=12&progress<15){
 
                }
                reverb.setEnabled(true);
                mediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(reverb.getId());
                mediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
            }
        });
 
 
        LoudnessEnhancer enhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
 
        ampController.setOnProgressChangedListener(new DrawspinControllers.onProgressChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int progress) {
                System.out.println("------AMP--------------------" + progress);//prints 1to15
                if (progress == 1) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(10);
                } else if (progress == 2) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(20);
                } else if (progress == 3) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(30);
                } else if (progress == 4){
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(40);
                }else if(progress==5){
                        enhancer.setTargetGain(50);
                }if (progress == 6) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(60);
                } else if (progress == 7) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(70);
                } else if (progress == 8) {
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(80);
                } else if (progress == 9){
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(90);
                }else if(progress==10){
                    enhancer.setTargetGain(100);
                }
                //gos to 15 on emulater
               enhancer.setEnabled(true);
            }
 
 
               });


k the loudness enhancer works i was just using values that are to small now i am using value between 100- 2000 and it works fine still have not gotten reverb to work
